# How to create a CLI program with "shell prompt"?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, prompt

I'm very new in programming. The following task looks very simple but I don't know how to do it. Appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance.

I'm using Linux OS. I would like to create a CLI program and let the user run it in shell terminal. I plan to use Bash shell script to create this program, but C++ or Perl should be ok too. The CLI program will accept commands from the user, execute it, and then optionally show the result summary on the screen.

When the CLI program is running, I would like to make it always shows a "shell prompt" at the left-hand side of the shell terminal, just like the Bash shell prompt. The prompt indicates that the CLI program is waiting for the user to type in a command and press the return key.

```
[AAA@Bash user]$ # This is Bash shell
[AAA@Bash user]$./CliApp.sh
CliApp > # The CLI program is running, user can type in command here
CliApp > exit
[AAA@Bash user]$ # Now the user has returned to the Bash shell
```

I think I know how to print something on the screen and get inputs from the users, but I found that it looks very unprofessional. I believe that there is a better way to create this kind of program.

Can anyone give me some guidance how to create this kind of program? Appreciate if you can give me the links to any example program. Thanks.

Comment: Show what you have so far and ask specific questions about it.

Comment: what, exactly, do you think looks unprofessional?  The example you provided looks just like executing commands from a shell.  Do you have examples of unprofessional-appearing components?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would like to create a shell prompt for my program. The prompt should remember the "environment" where the user is currently located. Example is the Cisco IOS software. When the user first login, the prompt is "Router>". After user key in password, it becomes "Router#". If the user enter the command "config terminal". It will becomes "Router(config)#". If the user want to configure an interface, the prompt will becomes "Router(config-if)#". The "environment" will determine which commands the user can use. Certain commands can only be executed in certain environment.

Comment: Just to help with your research, this kind of interface can also be called a REPL (Read Eval Print Loop), which I suspect may be a subclass of CLIs.

Comment: If you were writing your app in **C**, then you could use the readline library to get typical user history and line-editing features.  Not sure if something similar exists for bash...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a command interpreter through shell script sounds a bit redundant to me, since you must be using a command interpreter (bash, csh, sh, or something else) to be able to do that.

It is possible to customize your bash prompt if that's what you're looking for.

There are some C/C++ libraries you could used to assist you on building your own command processor/interpreter, that includes *fancy* features, like tab completion. You should take look at these:

- [The GNU Readline Library](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)
- [Editline Library](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/)

Comment: "Customizing bash" here could mean simply creating functions (or putting scripts onto the `PATH`) that do the things you want in your app, but directly within bash.  (For example I use bash/zsh daily but with a bunch of extra commands available from [my own library](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh) on the `PATH`.)

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something along the lines of the following?

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                    
input=""
while [ "$input" != "exit" ]
do
    echo -n "cliApp($mode) > " && read input
    if [ "$input" = "config" ]
    then
        mode="config"
    elif [ "$input" = "up" ]
    then
        mode=""
    elif [ "$input" = "exit" ]
    then
    break
    else
        if [ "$mode" = "config" ]
        then
            if [ "$input" = "list" ]
            then
                echo "ABCD"
            else
                echo "Invalid"
            fi
        else
            echo "Invalid"
        fi
    fi
done

exit
```